# In java if i want to use 10 interfaces in one class then it gets difficult?

Tags: java

I have 10 interfaces 
so i want to use those interfaces in one class

```
class def implements a,b,c,d,e,f,g
{
}
```

so instead of calling all interfaces i want to call only one interface where i can get all interfaces. Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Comment: "It gets difficult": how?

Comment: Make an interface H which `extends A, B, C, D, E, F, G`. Then make `def` implement `H`. That's ugly though. And extending interfaces just to avoid writing them is against every OOP principle.

Comment: I think having 10 interfaces that a class must implement those are over abstraction!!

Comment: if i have 10 interfaces then if i want to use all this interfaces in one class then if i write code  like this class def implements 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  is this right way?

Comment: If you think your class needs to implement 10 interfaces, then maybe you should rethink the design of your application. Are you sure you really need this, or is your class `def` a [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)?

Comment: i already gave implementations to all those interfaces

Comment: @Kurellavishal Yes this is the syntax.

Comment: Unrelated: read about java naming conventions. Even in examples: class names go UpperCase, always. And single char names are all but bad ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can do something like

```
interface iDef extends a,b,c,d,e,f,g
{
} 

class def implements iDef 
{
}
```

But in 99.99%, it shows some problems in design of your application:

- Why class `def` need to use such many interfaces?
- May be better to divide `def` class to many separate classes?

Answer (score 3):

There is no "practical" limit to how many interfaces you `implement` on your class.

But there is the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In a sound design, any class (or method in that class) should have exactly **one** responsibility.

Most likely, implementing 10 interfaces tells you right there: you are violating that principle.

And no matter if you "pull" interfaces together by having a "joiner" interface that extends multiple other interfaces, or if you just put down `implements I1, I2, I3, ...` in your class definition: that part is only "syntax". The real problem is of conceptual nature, and how you express in source code "I have a problem" doesn't matter.